# Spring mvc dispatcher configuration

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have a problem with my dispatcher servlet when I try to add to my dispatcher

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManager"/>
</beans:bean>
```

I have a problem Multiple 'annotations found at this line:

> - Class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' not found
> - Class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' not found [config set: NOVEC_App/web-
>      context]'

Comment: share your pom.xml / classpath. It seems that you are missing `spring-orm.jar`

Comment: I resolved it i just change the version of spring-orm.jar but i have some warning 'A short-cut alternative to a nested "<ref bean='...'/>"' can you help please

Comment: update the question with complete warning text and relevant configs.